# Changing ng-class based on conditional statement in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to update ng-class with a CSS class that has a specific background image. For example:

```
<button id="search" ng-class="{travel: travel }">Search</button>

for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

    var descriptions = uniqueFilters[i].split(' ');

       if(descriptions.indexOf('Travel') > -1) {
           $scope.travel = "travel";

             } else {

                }
           }}
```

I receive an array of strings. I take the strings, split the sentences into individual words, and then if they have a specific word, update the class to apply a specific background image.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Whatever you are using as the conditional in the `ng-class`, it needs to be a `boolean` value, not a `string`.  Maybe do something like:

`if(descriptions.indexOf('Travel') > -1) {`
           `$scope.travel = true;`

             `} else {`

             `}`
       `}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a function into the [`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive which needs to evaluate to either `true` or `false`.

If you create a function `travel` in your controller then pass it into the directive in your view:

```
<button id="search" ng-class="{travel: travel() }">Search</button>
```

In your controller:

```
// ... your other code

$scope.travel = function() {

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

    var descriptions = uniqueFilters[i].split(' ');

    if (descriptions.indexOf('Travel') > -1) {

      // we have satisfied our condition
      // the class 'travel' will be added to the button
      return true;

    }

  }

  // we didn't satisfy the condition in our loop
  // the class 'travel' will NOT be added to the button
  return false;

}
```

Comment: You could simplify that further with just a `return descriptions.indexOf('Travel') > -1`

Comment: @DaveV No you can't, it would return within the first iteration of the loop every time

Comment: ahhh, I didn't catch that the false was outside the loop, my bad

Comment: @DaveV Good thinking about it though!! :) - I've edited the code comments to make it a bit more clear

Answer (score 1):

As @Dave V said in his comment the ng-class directive requires a boolean value, so travel needs to be true:

```
$scope.travel = true;
```

Or if you need it to be a string, you can do something like:

```
ng-class="{travel: travel == 'travel' }"
```

Hope it helps =)